# python program tool into a web page

Tags: python, web-services

I made a program in python that I think would come well to put it on a web page for other people to use. But websites are beyond my knowledge. I hoped someone could guide me in what I have to do.

This program I made uses threading modules, web scraping, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please look into Flask as a starting point to build a simple web application.

- Installation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/installation/#install-flask
- Quickstart: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/

Then you can look into Full Stack Python. There are a lot of good resources on there:

- https://www.fullstackpython.com/